# Make Wordpress post edit left hand side column to be on top of right hand side column in small resolutions

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

In the Wordpress post edit screen, in narrow MOBILE displays, the left hand side column (where the title and the body wysiwyg editor is), displays BELOW the right hand side column (where the "Save" button is).

Is there a hook or filter to make the main left hand side column to display always on top of the right hand side column on narrow mobile displays?

I hope I make sense,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the theme you are using is buggy. Sounds like an css error. Try activating a standard wordpress theme that supports gutenberg and see if the error persists.